# Придача скорости объекту в сторону его поворота

Tags: c++

У меня есть объект. У него пять переменных: forceX, forceY, forceZ, rotationX, rotationY. Объекту нужно придать скорость(force) в сторону поворота этого объекта. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что такое `в сторону поворота этого объекта` - направление, в котором он "смотрит"? В 3D для определения такого вектора нужно три компонента

Comment: Да, в ту сторону куда он смотрит. А какие же могут быть три компонента? Поворот в X, Y. Какой ещё один?

Comment: @MBo Третье число нужно для описания "крена", который в принципе не влияет на направление "вперед".

Comment: @Assert_failed Если поворот нулевой, куда направлено "вперед"? Что применяется сначала, rotationX или rotationY? В какую стороную они вращают вокруг своих осей?

Answer (score 1):

Если "Поворот в X, Y" означает вращение вокруг осей OX и OY, то возьмите вектор начального направления, и умножьте его на аффинные матрицы поворота вокруг соотв. осей ([матрицы здесь](https://compgraphics.info/3D/3d_affine_transformations.php)) в нужном порядке.

Если вектор начального направления был единичной длины, то компоненты результата умножаете на абсолютную величину force